# Set Startup URL for Visual Studio Docker-Compose project

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-container-tools

I am using the container tools for Visual Studio 2019.  With them I have a docker compose project in my solution.  When that project is run, it starts up two separate containers.  (This works correctly.)

It also starts up a browser and goes to a URL.  The URL it is going to is wrong, and I want to change it.  But I can't find anything that controls the URL.

The Docker-Compose project file has some settings in it like `DockerServiceUrl` and `DockerLaunchAction`, but changing these has no effect on the url that is launched.

**How can I change the startup url for a Docker Compose Orchestration Project in Visual Studio 2019?**

Comment: When you right click on the docker compose project  and click "Properties" from the resulting context menu, what is the __Service URL__ property value in the General section?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule - {Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}

Comment: do you need to [set startup URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/property-pages-settings-for-web-projects?view=vs-2019) in web application project itself?

Comment: @timur - The docker compose file starts two different web applications.  The problem is that it is starting the wrong one.

Comment: when applications run, what does `docker ps` command output looks like?

Comment: @timur - Both containers start up just fine.  I am able to change my URL to the "other" container and it works just fine.  It is just the default / startup URL that I cannot seem to change.

Comment: The startup URL wouldn't it be under Project -> Properties -> LaunchSettings.json. Find the profile relevant and give a try?

Answer (score 7):

[Tutorial: Create a multi-container app with Docker Compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/tutorial-multicontainer?view=vs-2019)

The first project that you use when you add container orchestration is set up to be launched when you run or debug. You can configure the launch action in the **Project Properties** for the docker-compose project. On the docker-compose project node, right-click to open the context menu, and then **choose Properties**, or use Alt+Enter. The following screenshot shows the properties you would want for the solution used here. For example, you can change the page that is loaded by customizing the **Service URL** property.

[image]

Comment: This is the first time that I feel my answer was stolen on stackoverflow.com.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258558/how-to-deal-with-a-stolen-answer

Comment: This is all just a misunderstanding. At the time I initially answered, the Orchestration Project was opening in the Visual Studio text editor on left click. So I provided an answer aligned with that behavior. After working with the team at Microsoft, I updated Visual Studio and the behavior went away, which required a new answer. The OP also asked another question, so I bundled it all together and edited the answer.

Comment: +1 This is the correct way to edit the Service Url. I deleted my overlapping answer to prevent confusion.

Comment: Thank you,  your answer is much more detail, it's not bad .  Your words has calmed me down. I admit that I viewed the question for bounty but I just felt bad not for losing the bounty.  It's the Technological atmosphere attracted me most on stackoverflow.  So thank you.

Comment: I tried manually use a port number instead of {ServicePort} but it's not working. Is there a way to use a static port number?

Comment: @RodTalingting, you probably need to add the specific port number to the port mapping for the service in the docker-compose file.

Answer (score 3):

- Right-click the docker-compose project and go to properties.
- There you can configure the Service URL that gets launched on run.